# mysql statement error .No result

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so right now i am generating a report from submit button and it has two input type that are from and to   but the thing is i want from and too date and the result isnt showing up from the database

```
    $order_time=$_POST["datefrom"];
    $order_time=$_POST["dateto"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ss_orders where order_time='".$order_time."' limit 60";
```

Thats my above code , so is it possible to use between in that above query ? and also my data type in the database of order_time is datetime ? so why i am not getting any result ?

Thanks in advance :) Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Of-course you can use between but can u make sure $order_time contains some value and if yes which format ?

Comment: Well if your above code is your actual code, you're not getting a result because you're not actually performing a query. You're creating an SQL string but you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: make sure your `$order_time` has the value like `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: echo your query and run it in xampp (or any other) and see what error is given out there

Comment: @MLeFevre i have the code that generates report in xls format , too long to post it here

Comment: @Butterfruit i did but it says no records found

Comment: why are u using same variable order_time for both input. why dont do an if else. secondly is your date time format is same as in db

Answer (score 2):

```
$order_time=$_POST["datefrom"];
$s= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($order_time)); 
$order_timeto=$_POST["dateto"];
$e= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($order_timeto)); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM ss_orders where datetime<=$s and datetime>=$e";
```

Comment: That's not how you format dates using `date()`. `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order_time));` <- this is the way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

as a programmer you should check and debug your code in all possible ways,you can print what are the values these variables having and you cal also print the query so you can know what is the actual query executing.

```
 $fromdate=$_POST["datefrom"];
 $todate=$_POST["dateto"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ss_orders where datetime<='$todate' and datetime>='$fromdate' limit 60";
```

and `PDO/MYsqli` for security